# Google Apps Script PUT requests failing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-api

I'm having issues with calling the [Streak API](https://streak.readme.io/v9/reference#put-an-email-in-a-box) with Google Apps Script.  Any of the GET or POST requests I make are working, but I can't get a single PUT request to work.

Since the matching CURL requests work I'm thinking it's something I'm doing wrong with the GAS request?  Any help would be appreciated!

For example this:

```
  var streakApiKey = "<my-api-key>";
  var streakBoxKey = "agxzfm1haWxmb29nYWVyLwsSDE9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbiIQd2hlZWx3b3Jrcy5jby5uegwLEgRDYXNlGKGs7kkM";
  var gmailThreadId = "1611ad242bc28086";
  var url = "https://www.streak.com/api/v1/boxes/" + streakBoxKey + "/threads/";

  var payload = {
    "boxKey": streakBoxKey,
    "threadGmailId": gmailThreadId
    };

  var headers = {
     "Accept": "application/json",
     "Content-Type": "application/json",
     "Authorization": "Basic "+ Utilities.base64Encode(streakApiKey + ":")
     };

  var options = {
    "method": "put",
    "headers": headers,
    "contentType" : "application/json",
    "payload": JSON.stringify(payload),
    "muteHttpExceptions" : true,
    };

  var request = UrlFetchApp.getRequest(url, options);
  Logger.log(request);

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
```

Returns:

```
[18-02-04 10:58:30:284 NZDT] {headers={Authorization=Basic <my-encoded-api-key>, Accept=application/json}, method=put, payload={"boxKey":"agxzfm1haWxmb29nYWVyLwsSDE9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbiIQd2hlZWx3b3Jrcy5jby5uegwLEgRDYXNlGKGs7kkM","threadGmailId":"1611ad242bc28086"}, followRedirects=true, validateHttpsCertificates=true, useIntranet=false, contentType=application/json, url=https://www.streak.com/api/v1/boxes/agxzfm1haWxmb29nYWVyLwsSDE9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbiIQd2hlZWx3b3Jrcy5jby5uegwLEgRDYXNlGKGs7kkM/threads/}
[18-02-04 10:58:30:311 NZDT] {
  "success": false,
  "error": "Insufficient params for GmailThread. Missing json"
}
```

But this CURL works:

```
 curl --request PUT \  --url https://www.streak.com/api/v1/boxes/agxzfm1haWxmb29nYWVyLwsSDE9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbiIQd2hlZWx3b3Jrcy5jby5uegwLEgRDYXNlGKGs7kkM/threads \  --data 'boxKey=agxzfm1haWxmb29nYWVyLwsSDE9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbiIQd2hlZWx3b3Jrcy5jby5uegwLEgRDYXNlGKGs7kkM&threadGmailId=1611ad242bc28086' -u <my-api-key>:
```

Similarly this fails:

```
var streakApiKey = "<my-api-key>";
  var pipelineKey = "agxzfm1haWxmb29nYWVyNwsSDE9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbiIQd2hlZWx3b3Jrcy5jby5uegwLEghXb3JrZmxvdxiAgICA1uaPCgw";
  var url = "https://www.streak.com/api/v1/pipelines/" + pipelineKey + "/stages";

  var payload = {
    "name": "new Stage from API",
    };

  var headers = {
     "Accept": "application/json",
     "Content-Type": "application/json",
     "Authorization": "Basic "+ Utilities.base64Encode(streakApiKey + ":")
     };

  var options = {
    "method": "put",
    "headers": headers,
    "contentType" : "application/json",
    "payload": JSON.stringify(payload),
    "muteHttpExceptions" : true,
    };

  var request = UrlFetchApp.getRequest(url, options);
  Logger.log(request);

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
```

and returns:

```
[18-02-04 11:02:01:600 NZDT] {headers={Authorization=Basic <my-encoded-api-key>, Accept=application/json}, method=put, payload={"name":"new Stage from API"}, followRedirects=true, validateHttpsCertificates=true, useIntranet=false, contentType=application/json, url=https://www.streak.com/api/v1/pipelines/agxzfm1haWxmb29nYWVyNwsSDE9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbiIQd2hlZWx3b3Jrcy5jby5uegwLEghXb3JrZmxvdxiAgICA1uaPCgw/stages}
[18-02-04 11:02:01:632 NZDT] {
  "success": false,
  "error": "Insufficient params for Stage"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points :

- From your curl sample, it seems that the data is sent as "form-data".
- In your GAS sample, it seems that the data is sent as "data".
- When "Content-Type" is "application/json", the data is sent as "data".
- When `JSON.stringify()` is used for "payload" withoud "application/json", "form-data" is sent as a string.

The modified scripts which reflected above points are as follows.

#### For sample 1 :

```
var streakApiKey = "<my-api-key>";
var streakBoxKey = "agxzfm1haWxmb29nYWVyLwsSDE9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbiIQd2hlZWx3b3Jrcy5jby5uegwLEgRDYXNlGKGs7kkM";
var gmailThreadId = "1611ad242bc28086";
var url = "https://www.streak.com/api/v1/boxes/" + streakBoxKey + "/threads/";
var payload = {
  "boxKey": streakBoxKey,
  "threadGmailId": gmailThreadId
};
var headers = {
//  "Accept": "application/json", // Modified (I couldn't confirm whether this is required.)
//  "Content-Type": "application/json", // Modified
  "Authorization": "Basic "+ Utilities.base64Encode(streakApiKey + ":")
};
var options = {
  "method": "put",
  "headers": headers,
//  "contentType" : "application/json", // Modified
  "payload": payload, // Modified
  "muteHttpExceptions" : true,
};
var request = UrlFetchApp.getRequest(url, options);
Logger.log(request);
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
Logger.log(response.getContentText());
```

#### For sample 2 :

```
var streakApiKey = "<my-api-key>";
var pipelineKey = "agxzfm1haWxmb29nYWVyNwsSDE9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbiIQd2hlZWx3b3Jrcy5jby5uegwLEghXb3JrZmxvdxiAgICA1uaPCgw";
var url = "https://www.streak.com/api/v1/pipelines/" + pipelineKey + "/stages";
var payload = {
  "name": "new Stage from API",
};
var headers = {
//  "Accept": "application/json", // Modified (I couldn't confirm whether this is required.)
//  "Content-Type": "application/json", // Modified
  "Authorization": "Basic "+ Utilities.base64Encode(streakApiKey + ":")
};
var options = {
  "method": "put",
  "headers": headers,
//  "contentType" : "application/json", // Modified
  "payload": payload, // Modified
  "muteHttpExceptions" : true,
};
var request = UrlFetchApp.getRequest(url, options);
Logger.log(request);
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
Logger.log(response.getContentText());
```

#### Note :

- I cannot test these modified scripts, because I don't have token and key. So please test this.

If this didn't work, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Tristan Welcome. I'm glad your problem was solved. Thank you, too.